# Arduino GSM Implementation

Tags: gsm, gps

I want to send sms to a number if and only if that number is in the radius of the arduino with GSM module.

I already have GPS into it.

Should i integrate a ultrasonic sensor to get the distance and then send the message??? let me know if there is anyother option.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of radius are we talking about? Line-of-sight ultrasonic sensor radius? But how are you planing to determine the number with ultrasonic sensor?

Comment: Can't be done without writing a special app for the phone - and then the sending of the SMS is pointless.